# Mac bundle does not load in Mac Catalyst in M2 Chip

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a Mac bundle in my Mac Catalyst app which has some external libraries (Only Mac supported ones) which is working fine with **Intel based Mac** and  **Mac Catalyst Rosetta in M2 Mac**.

But when I run with Mac Catalyst targeting an M2 Mac, it shows the below error. I have checked a couple of answers in S.O but they were not helpful.

- EDIT 1

  In Xcode We have option to ***Open Using Rosetta*** , Is there any way to provide that option for my Mac Catalyst app  ?

> /Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle
> (218):
> dlopen(/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle,
> 0x0109): tried:
> '/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug/MacSupportBundle'
> (no such file),
> '/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MacSupportBundle'
> (no such file), '/usr/lib/system/introspection/MacSupportBundle' (no
> such file, not in dyld cache),
> '/System/iOSSupport/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle'
> (no such file),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/System/iOSSupport/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle'
> (no such file),
> '/System/iOSSupport/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle'
> (no such file),
> '/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64')),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle'
> (no such file),
> '/Users/prashanttukadiya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-ccmfxiugfduiapdmdcagdwvcxlww/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyAPP_TNG.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacSupportBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MacSupportBundle'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64'))